# Vector image of square grid

Tags: svg

I'm trying to create an SVG image made of an array of squares at given positions. I used to create a bmp image with Matlab and use an image vectorizing tool like inkscape to export it as SVG. As you might expect, Inkscape creates polygons that approximate the squares. Those aren't very accurate and make an uneven array of rectangles of different sizes.

I assume this is very easy to do. I'm really new to SVG's so I tried something like:

```
<svg width="400" height="100">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10">
    <rect x="20" y="10" width="10" height="10">
    <rect x="10" y="20" width="10" height="10">
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="10" height="10">
</svg>
```

However this seems to create a single square. Having a list of positions (like a Matlab vector), what is the easiest way to accomplish something like that? Is it possible to create a loop that goes through all positions of a given vector?

Comment: I just noticed that each rectangle line should've ended in "/>". I was thinking they shouldn't merge into one since they're located at different positions.

Comment: Didn't norice that either. The missing /> will mean that you only see the first one as the rest would be invalid nested rect elements.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to produce a number of uniform squares is a path like this:

```
<path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="square"
  d="M20,20h0 M40,20h0 M60,20h0"/>
```

But be aware of bugs for paths with zero line length. At least some implementations fail if you do that with `stroke-linecap="round"` to produce circles instead of squares. A workaround is to use a small, but non-zero line length, e.g. `M20,20h.1`. You can also use `stroke-linecap="butt"` (the default):

```
<path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10"
  d="M20,20h10 M40,20h10 M60,20h10"/>
```